# Writing a batch orientated program

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

A professor takes 100-point exams that are graded on the scale 90-100:A, 80-89:B etc. The input file is exam.txt and must write to grade.txt . This is my code but it does not work well:

```
infile = open("exam.txt","r")
outfile = open("grade.txt","w")

for line in infile:
    line = int(line)
    if line>=90:
        print("A", file=outfile)
    elif line>=80 and line<=89:
        print("B", file=outfile)
    elif line>=70 and line<=79:
        print("C", file = outfile)
    elif line>=60 and line<=69:
        print("D", file=outfile)
    elif line>=50 and line<=59:
        print("E", file=outfile)
    else:
        print("F", file= outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
infile = open("fin.txt","r")
outfile = open("grade.txt","w")

for line in infile:
    line = int(line)
    if line>=90:
        outfile.write("%s --> A \n" %line)
    elif line>=80 and line<=89:
        outfile.write("%s --> B \n" %line)
    elif line>=70 and line<=79:
        outfile.write("%s --> C \n" %line)
    elif line>=60 and line<=69:
        outfile.write("%s --> D \n" %line)
    elif line>=50 and line<=59:
        outfile.write("%s --> E \n" %line)
    else:
        outfile.write("%s --> F \n" %line)

outfile.close()
```